# Restarting Computer via VBS

Tags: vbscript

I need a less dogey/more efficient way to restart my computer through VBS. The code below is an example of what I have so far. Is there a more efficient way to restart other then SendKeys method??

```
Option Explicit
Dim obj
set obj= creatobject("wscript.shell")    
    obj.run "CMD"
    wscript.sleep 300
    obj.SendKeys "shutdown /r"
    obj.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    obj.SendKeys "exit"
    obj.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    wscript.quit
```

Thanks

Comment: Why `SendKeys`? Just run the executable. `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "shutdown.exe /r"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use winmgmts, this script takes an argument for the computer name but can easily be changed for your use

```
If Wscript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    strComputer = inputbox("Enter a computer name to Restart","Enter computer name")
    if strComputer = "" then wscript.quit
Else
    strCOmputer = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)

End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    objOperatingSystem.Reboot()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work

```
Set OpSysSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{authenticationlevel=Pkt," _
     & "(Shutdown)}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where "_
     & "Primary=true")
for each OpSys in OpSysSet
    retVal = OpSys.Reboot()
next
```